# CSS3 Scale not working for <a> in Firefox 34.0.5

Tags: css, firefox, transform, scale

I have a query about using a CSS3 scale transform. Can anyone explain why this scale transform doesn't work in Firefox (currently using 34.0.5), but does in Opera?

HTML:

```
<a href="#">hover me!</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
       -o-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
     -moz-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
       -o-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
          transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
       -o-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}
```

[>> JSFiddle here <<](http://jsfiddle.net/DaniRodr80/501yrpx1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the link to `display: inline-block`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/501yrpx1/1/)

---

Link is an inline element. And CSS transformations cannot be applied to it as [mentioned here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering):

> Transforms apply to transformable elements.

[Transformable elements are](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>     property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>     table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or
>     gradientTransform [SVG11].

Comment: Thank you Salman A!
I could have sworn I tried that with the live code and it didn't work, perhaps I didn't Ctrl+F5 it.  Anyway, thanks, it helps to have the details explained too!